# Obtener SelectedIndex de DropDownList - ASP .NET MVC 2 desde Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una pagina con *MVC 2*, que tenía en el **.aspx**, código *Javascript*, pero como necesito usar esa página desde un *widget* nativo de *iOS*, quiero analizar un *XML*. Tuve que quitar el código *Javascript* a un archivo aparte debido a que por los `&&`, `>` y `<` no lo analiza correctamente, y no me carga la página.

Quiero obtener el valor de un *DropDownList* que está en el **.aspx** desde el archivo **.js**.

El *DropDownList* lo tengo así:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList(
    Model.RegistrationDocumentTypeKey,
    Model.GetDocumentTypes(),
    new {
        @id = Model.RegistrationDocumentTypeKey,
        onchange = "onDocumentTypeChangeAux()",
        selectedIndex = 1
    }
)%>
```

Quisiera obtener el valor del índice seleccionado desde el método `onDocumentTypeChangeAux()`.

Antes de mover el código *Javascript* al archivo, estaba así, y funcionaba:

```
var ddl = document.getElementById('<%=  Model.RegistrationDocumentTypeKey %>');
switch (ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value) ...
```

Pero ahora, así no funciona, intenté cambiarlo poniendo solo el `id`, haciéndolo como con *jQuery*, pero no he tenido éxito.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar el método siguiente para obtener el Id del dropdownlist:

```
$('#tusDropDownList').change(function () { /* Esto es el evento del cambio de ddl */     
    /* Obtener el valor de tus dropdownlist */
    var selectedId = $(this).val();
});
```

Espero que esto ayude...